# Pantone for printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-production, pantone

I have a project of packaging. I ask my printer if the file should be in cmyk and he said that he only work with Pantone.
Is it normal? Doesn’t it cost a lot for Pantone?

Comment: What are you printing? What kind of image? And what printing method?  If it's single colour printing, then a Pantone colour is generally cheaper to print. It requires only one plate, and one colour of ink.  CMYK printing uses four plates, and four inks.

Comment: It is a box of chocolates and one etiquette for another box with different colors and text.

Answer (score 0):

Ask them why.

But one assumption is that the machine they use is pretty small. Let me explain.

Having a CMYK file means that you need to register, or print very accurately the different color passes, so the machine has different mechanisms to do this, including being a very sturdy machine.

There are some that can print each of the 4 colors consecutively, so they are known as 4 head presses. Imagine 8-10 m of machinery.

There are smaller ones, with 2 heads, so they need to print 2 colors and then change the inks and plates.

But even 1 head printer, if they have the mechanisms to accurately print, can do a CMYK print. It takes longer to do so because you need to change plate and clean the machine 4 times, but they can. I have use them see them a lot.

But if the printer is tiny, they can print 1 color and have no way of printing the next color accurately.

That is the only reason I can think of.

Rejecting a project that can be 4 times bigger (4 inks), to print only a spot ink has no sense unless this kind of limitations.

---

Even if the print process is not sheetfed offset, the point is similar. You can even print a CMYK project on a silkscreen or screen print! which is a manual process.

Comment: Thank you so much I will ask him !

Comment: Do you think I should have the paper swatches of Pantone ?